# Azure exception being thrown

Tags: c#, .net, azure, mono

I have an app which is reliant on an azure service. For most of the time, it's seamless, but I'm also getting this thrown back (it's caught in the app, so the app doesn't fail)

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:62 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00034] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:60 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+d__1c.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:62 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00034] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter_T.cs:59 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<RequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:62 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpResponse].GetResult () [0x00034] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter_T.cs:59 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable+<>c__DisplayClassf+<b__e>d__11.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0

edit - removed some of the stack trace

The code I'm using to send to the server is very simple

```
public static async Task<bool> StoreData<T>(T obj) where T:IIdentity
    {
        if (!ftrackData.Online)
            return false;
        try
        {
            #if __IOS__
            var test = await AppDelegate.MobileService.GetTable<T>().Where(t => t.id == obj.id).ToListAsync();

            if (test.Count != 0)
                await AppDelegate.MobileService.GetTable<T>().UpdateAsync(obj);
            else
                await AppDelegate.MobileService.GetTable<T>().InsertAsync(obj);


            /*using (var <List<T>> test = AppDelegate.MobileService.GetTable<T>().Where(t => t.id == obj.id).ToListAsync())
            {
                var tmp = new List<T>();
                test.ContinueWith((res) =>
                {
                    tmp = res.Result;
                    if (tmp.Count != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("updating data");
                        AppDelegate.MobileService.GetTable<T>().UpdateAsync(obj);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("inserting data");
                        AppDelegate.MobileService.GetTable<T>().InsertAsync(obj);
                        Console.WriteLine("data inserted");
                    }
                });*/
            #else
                using (var<List<T>> test = ftrack2.Singleton.MobileService.GetTable<T>().Where(t => t.id == obj.id).ToListAsync())
                {
            var tmp = new List<T>();
            test.ContinueWith((res) =>
            {
            tmp = res.Result;
            if (tmp.Count != 0)
            ftrack2.Singleton.MobileService.GetTable<T>().UpdateAsync(obj);
            else
            ftrack2.Singleton.MobileService.GetTable<T>().InsertAsync(obj);
            });
            }
            #endif
            return true;

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in StoreData thrown : {0}-{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The commented out section was a different attempt, again, it worked, but didn't work as async.

Is there anything else I can be doing to ensure that I don't get this throwback from the server?

Comment: That is an unreadable wall of text. Please include only necessary information in your question and format it appropriately- the odds of anybody actually reading what you've pasted here are quite slim. (Also, the code formatting is messed up)

Comment: Sorry - when giving throw back, usually the more you have to work from, the better. I've removed some of it now.

Comment: Any luck in getting this resolved? Facing the same exception, but can't find any more specific error as to why it would throw this exception?